# gnuplot frequency chart timestamp

Tags: plot, graph, charts, gnuplot, gnu

I have a list of timestamps like shown at the end, and I am trying to make a histogram/frequency chart where the X-axis is the time and the y axis a count of the frequency. I tried doing something like this:

```
set term dumb
set xdata
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
set xrange ["16/04/2018":"14/04/2018"]
plot 'dat'
```

and in the data file

```
2018-04-16T14:54:38Z
2018-04-16T13:50:07Z
2018-04-16T12:30:45Z
2018-04-16T11:45:16Z
2018-04-16T11:44:11Z
2018-04-16T10:19:19Z
2018-04-16T10:13:25Z
2018-04-16T00:17:33Z
2018-04-15T23:10:15Z
2018-04-14T22:27:34Z
2018-04-14T23:11:29Z
2018-04-14T22:45:08Z
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErI0j.png)

As you can see the x axis does not represent the time.

EDIT:

With Christoph's fixed code, the result is a plot of the timestamp and row the number.

To better explain the problem I have:
I want to plot the time on the x-axis and I want to plot the number of occurrences of the timestamp on the y-axis and where the timestamps are binned to some value in hours and possibly instead of just drawing bars it would interpolate lines between the peaks of the bars.

Comment: Ok, and what is the actual problem? You haven't formulated any real question?

Comment: What I meant to say is that I tried the above I don't get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I asked for you actual question, because the code you posted doesn't create any plot. Let's see:

If I execute only the code you posted, I get the error `all points y value undefined!`.

- In plot time data on the x axis, you need `set xdata time`.

Having set that you would get as next error `Need full using spec for x time data`. Indeed, you *must* have a `using` when handling time data, something like

- `plot 'dat' using 1:0`

Then, you would again get the error `all points y value undefined!`. This time, because the time strings given in `set xrange` must match those specified with `set timefmt`.

So, a working version of your code could be:

```
reset
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
set xrange ["2018-04-16":"2018-04-14"]
plot 'dat' using 1:0
```

This plots time on the xaxis, and the row number on the y-axis.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the code, I edited the description; hopefully it explains the problem better now.